# Which star has the highest estimated mass-loss rate?

Tags: mass, red-supergiant, mass-loss

As far as I know, stars like RSGs and LBVs have the highest mass loss rates. There is Eta Carinae (0.00039 solar masses/yr), NML Cygni (0.00042 - 0.00048 solar masses/yr), WOH G64 (0.00072 solar masses/yr), IRAS 05280-6910 (0.00098 solar masses/yr) and finally IRAS 05346-6949 (0.0017 solar masses/yr). Are there any stars with similar or higher mass loss rates?

Comment: Would be nice, if you could flesh-out your question with citing the sources of your information. you likely did not measure (all of) these yourself :) - and preferably also state which other sources you consulted, but which did not give you additional information.

Comment: @planetmaker Eta Carinae - https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/ace596 NML Cygni - https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-3881/aab961 WOH G64 and IRAS 05280-6910 - https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/ac6dcf IRAS 05346-6949 - https://keele-repository.worktribe.com/output/409792

Comment: Seems like there's Stephenson 2 DFK 49 - the mass-loss rate is 0.00077 solar masses/yr

Comment: Your should incorporate the links in your comment into the question text